# get value of cookie form cookieManager.getCookieStore() in android

Tags: android, eclipse, cookies, httpcookie

SetCookie function is supposed to set cookie and GetCookie is supposed to read value of cookie.SetCookie works fine but getcookie encounters an exception beacuse `cookieManager.getCookieStore().get(new URI("https://archive.irib.ir/"))` return empty string and it's size is 0. How can I read a value of my cookie????

here is my SetCookie and GetCookie

```
    public void SetCookie(String Value) {
    try
    {
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("lang", Value);

        cookie.setDomain("archive.irib.ir");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setVersion(0);
        cookie.setValue(Value);
        cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI("https://archive.irib.ir/"), cookie);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {


    }
}
public String GetCookie() {
    try
    {
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        List<HttpCookie> Cookies =  cookieManager.getCookieStore().get(new URI("https://archive.irib.ir/"));
        //Integer s = Cookies.size();
        return Cookies.get(0).getValue().toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are using different cookieManager instance in each function, try creating a static cookieManager instance or define it like member class.